# iOS Reachability Unknown Moment

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I am using Apple's Reachability class in my app to be noticed when I am on or off the network, so that I know if I should get data from online or locally.

My issue is, there is a small 3-5 second gap. If I disconnect from a network, e.g. turn on Airplane mode, its takes 3-5 seconds before I am notified that I am no longer on any network.

This means, if I try to fetch any data in the app during that period, it thinks I am online and as such fails to get data etc.

How can I handle this gap? If don't know the moment the device goes offline, this seems like a difficult issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the reachability class in AppDelegate.m like this:

```
Reachability *internetReachable;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    // Set up Reachability
    internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

    // check for internet connection
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    [internetReachable startNotifier];

- (void)checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice {
    // called after network status changes

    if ( connected]) {
       // Your code HERE!
    }

}

- (BOOL)connected {
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works identically to my existing Reachability code. There is still a notable gap between loosing network connectivity and being notified.